# how can load gmap link on mobile browser

Tags: google-maps, mobile-website

I just created a page to display google map using gmap api and map displaying well on the pc but when i send this link http://ratebol.com/statmap_v3.php to mobile map is not displaying.

Please give me solution to display map on mobile...

Comment: You are not giving a lot of detail here. First, please include a well-formatted relevant code example in the question (since this question will otherwise be worthless as soon as the link you provide stop working). Second, you do not state what mobile device you are using.

An old Nokia WAP-browser with no JavaScript will not display much, but an iPhone or Android device should.

Answer (score 3):

On the iPhone you can call either of the methods below.  I recommend that you use method #2 since it will work on mobile or non-mobile devices.

Method #1

```
<a href="maps:q=Austin, TX">Austin, Map</a>
```

Method #2

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;q=austin,+tx">Austin, Map</a>
```

This method (#2) is parsed with you click the link. The iPhone and other devices see "maps.google.com" and know to launch the Google Maps application if installed and supported by the device. Otherwise it will open in the browser.